# Python: How do I print a tuple using try and except?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

Python: Im checking to see if a list has all digits, if yes, print them as tuple(a), if not, print an Error message. My code is printing both the error and the tuple(a) if the list contains letters, how can i just print the error message without the tuple?

```
    #list_to_tuple function goes here
def list_to_tuple(a_list):
a = []
for i in a_list:
    try:
        i = int(i)
        a.append(i)
    except:  
        print("Error. Please enter only integers.")

print(tuple(a))


def main():
   a_list = input("Enter elements of list separated by commas:").strip().split(',')
   list_to_tuple(a_list)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a `return` command under where you print the error.

```
  except:
        print("Error. Please enter only integers.")
        return
```

like this. This should work.

Comment: wow didn't think of this, thank you! Can you explain why this works, shouldn't the print(tuple(a)) still print after the return is complete?

Comment: @BurmesePapi `return` returns you back to where you called the function. No coming back!